# Help with friend with many allergies

Tags: substitutions

I'm having a friends family over for dinner next week, Ang they have numerous allergies or sensitivities.  Corn,  gluten,  soy, rice and citrus.  The dinner I planned on making,  contains quick cooking tapioca. Any ideas on what to to use in substitute for that?

Comment: Tapioca doesn't have gluten, did they specify that they can't eat it?

Answer (score 2):

Tapioca is Cassava starch, it's not a grain, soy product, or citrus so it should cause no issues with your friends. Just make sure there aren't any additives to the tapioca that could cause a reaction, for instance citric acid as a preservative.